# How do I run a Visual Studio C# program with command line arguments?

Tags: visual-studio, command-line

I have a very basic Visual Studio console app:

```
using System;

namespace BasicApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

I can run it just fine from inside Visual Studio by clicking the green triangle "Run" button, but I also want to be able to run it from the command line and pass it some arguments. I'm a little confused by the file structure of Visual Studio projects and I don't know too much about how compiling works. What do I need to type into the command line in order to make it run?

Comment: ...The path to the program, followed by the arguments? What did you try typing in that didn't work, and what happened?

Comment: If this is a .NET Framework (not .NET Core) project then the output executable will be in `bin\Debug\YourProjectName.exe` for Debug builds and `bin\Release\YourProjectName.exe` for Release builds.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I wasn't sure if I need to compile it in some special way, and I had a hard time finding where the executable was stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run the program with command line parameters in Visual Studio, you can go to the main menu and follow below order:

1. Project
2. BasicApp Properties
3. Debug
4. Start Options
5. Command line arguments:

After inputting your command line arguments there, the arguments will be passed to Visual Studio debugger.

Please see the attached screenshot.

[image: command line arguments for Visual Studio debugger]

Answer (score 1):

1. Under the "Build" tab, click "Build Solution".
2. Using command line, navigate to `MyProject\MyProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\`.
3. From inside the `netcoreapp3.0` directory, simply execute `MyProject.exe` from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2022 they created a new dialog for this:

- Open the project's properties (right click in Solution Exporer or via main menu)
- Select Debug
- Click the link "Open debug launch profiles UI"
- Type your arguments into the first field, "Command line arguments"
- Close the window (there is no Save-Button)
- Run your project in Debug mode to see your arguments